# Why this function runs correctly only once, and then returns an empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, xpath, imdb

This code scraps *IMDb* website (gets movie's titles, years, ranks, etc) with `XPath` expressions and returns their result but its `selector()` function only runs once correctly then breaks. How do I fix it?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import lxml.html
import requests as rq


IMDB_HTML = "http://www.imdb.com/filmosearch"
IMDB_JSON = "http://www.imdb.com/xml/find"


class IMDBParser(object):
    def __init__(self, role_type=None, sort_type='user_rating, desc',
                 job_type="actor", title_type="movie"):
        self.job_type = job_type
        self.sort_type = sort_type
        self.title_type = title_type
        self.role_type = role_type
        self.params = {
            'page': 0,
            'sort': sort_type,
            'role': role_type,
            'job_type': job_type,
            'title_type': title_type
        }

    def identity(self):
        """gets actor's name and extracts its id from
        imdb website."""
        response = rq.get(IMDB_JSON, params={'json': 1, 'nm': 'one',
                          'q': rq.compat.quote_plus(self.role_type)})
        movie_dicts = response.json()
        return movie_dicts.get('name_popular', 'name_approx')[0]['id']

    def selector(self, expr):
        """gets an expression and extracts all matched then
        returns a generator of each matching value."""
        self.params['role'] = self.identity()
        while True:
            self.params['page'] += 1
            response = rq.get(IMDB_HTML, params=self.params)
            elements = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text).xpath(expr)
            if not elements:
                break
            yield from (element.text for element in elements)


class IMDBApplication(IMDBParser):
    def __init__(self, role_type=None, sort_type='user_rating, desc',
                 job_type="actor", title_type="movie"):
        IMDBParser.__init__(self)
        self.job_type = job_type
        self.sort_type = sort_type
        self.title_type = title_type
        self.role_type = role_type

    def get_titles(self):
        """passes the xpath expression to the function and gets
        its return."""
        expr = "//*/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/h3/a[1]"
        return self.selector(expr)

    def get_scores(self):
        """passes the xpath expression to the function and gets
        its return."""
        expr = "//*/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/strong"
        return self.selector(expr)

    def get_years(self):
        """passes the xpath expression to the function and gets
        its return."""
        expr = "//*/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/h3/span[2]"
        return self.selector(expr)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ia1 = IMDBApplication("Daniel Craig")
    print([i for i in ia1.get_titles()])
    print([i for i in ia1.get_scores()])
```

Comment: How exactly does it break? Please provide more specifics.

Comment: @peterh - Code Review is for working code, not for debugging issues

Comment: Now you are over 15 repu, and so you can upvote answers, which is a big reward. And your nick is really funny :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is:

```
self.params['page'] += 1
```

One the first request, you increment the page number until you don't get any results. However, you never reset it. If you change your `selector` function to:

```
def selector(self, expr):
    """gets an expression and extracts all matched then
    returns a generator of each matching value."""
    self.params['role'] = self.identity()
    while True:
        self.params['page'] += 1
        response = rq.get(IMDB_HTML, params=self.params)
        elements = lxml.html.fromstring(response.text).xpath(expr)
        if not elements:
            break
        yield from (element.text for element in elements)
    self.params['page'] = 0
```

It works fine, giving:

```
['Casino Royale', 'The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo', 'One Life', 'Skyfall', 'Road to Perdition', 'Munich', 'Elizabeth', 'Layer Cake', 'The Adventures of Tintin: The Secret of the Unicorn', 'Defiance', 'The Power of One', 'The Jacket', 'Infamous', 'Sorstalanság', 'The Mother', 'Flashbacks of a Fool', 'Renaissance', 'Ten Minutes Older: The Cello', 'Quantum of Solace', 'Some Voices', 'Love Is the Devil: Study for a Portrait of Francis Bacon', 'Hotel Splendide', 'Enduring Love', 'Sylvia', 'The Golden Compass', 'Cowboys & Aliens', 'The Trench', 'Dream House', 'The Invasion', 'Lara Croft: Tomb Raider', 'I Dreamed of Africa', 'Obsession', 'Love & Rage', 'Saint-Ex', "A Kid in King Arthur's Court", 'Spectre', 'The Girl Who Played with Fire', 'Bond 25', "The Girl Who Kicked the Hornets' Nest"]
['8.0', '7.9', '7.9', '7.8', '7.7', '7.6', '7.5', '7.4', '7.4', '7.2', '7.2', '7.1', '7.1', '7.1', '6.9', '6.8', '6.8', '6.8', '6.7', '6.7', '6.6', '6.5', '6.4', '6.3', '6.1', '6.1', '6.1', '5.9', '5.9', '5.7', '5.5', '5.3', '5.3', '5.1', '4.7']
```